# I am fetching data from Firebase Realtime database but I get null object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an android application using Firebase Realtime Database. But I get Null Object every time. I am getting value in a Static Object, declare and Initialize in a Common class which extends the Application class;

1. This is my database Structure

[image]

2. Here Is my Code for fetching data

   ````
       void getLicRequest(String iid)
               {
                   DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("LicenseUpRequests");
                   Query qu=ref.orderByChild("id").equalTo(iid);
                   qu.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                           Commons k=(Commons)getApplicationContext();
                           k.licRequest=snapshot.getValue(LicenseModel.class);
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                       }
                   });
               }
       ```
   ````
3. This is my Model Class

   ````
    public class LicenseModel {
           public String frontSide;
           public String backSide;
           public String id;
           public String date;

           public String getFrontSide() {
               return frontSide;
           }

           public void setFrontSide(String frontSide) {
               this.frontSide = frontSide;
           }

           public String getBackSide() {
               return backSide;
           }

           public void setBackSide(String backSide) {
               this.backSide = backSide;
           }

           public String getId() {
               return id;
           }

           public void setId(String id) {
               this.id = id;
           }

           public String getDate() {
               return date;
           }

           public void setDate(String date) {
               this.date = date;
           }
       }
       ```
   ````

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your `onDataChange` will need to navigate this list, by looping over `snapshot.getChildren()`:

```
qu.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Commons k=(Commons)getApplicationContext();
        for (DataSnapshot requestSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            k.licRequest=requestSnapshot.getValue(LicenseModel.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // Never ignore errors
    }
});
```